# Verified slope of tangent line is...

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Find the slope of the tangent line to $f(x)=12\tan^{-1}(3x)$ at the point ($\frac{1}{3},3\pi)$

I got 18 for my answer. Can anybody please verified this, I have the feeling that it's wrong.

Please Help!!!

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Can you show your work?  What does the derivative $f'(x)$ look like (before evaluating)?

Comment: In my humble opinion SE can't help you concerning to what's wrong with your feelings -- talk about that with a person of your confidence.  In case you are unsure about your calculations, give us without any emotions a chance to catch a glimpse of them, please, and we'll try to detect any error in those, if there were any.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x)=12\arctan(3x)$ is [differentiable](http://oregonstate.edu/instruct/mth251/cq/Stage6/Lesson/invTrigDeriv.html) at any points in $\mathbb R$ with $$f'(x)=\frac{36}{1+9x^2}$$ So the slope of the line would be $f'(1/3)=18$ and the equation of the tangent line is $$y-3\pi=18(x-1/3)$$

[image]